# Getting exit status of terminated process

Tags: c, fork, wait, waitpid

I'm trying to get the exit status and of each process whether it returned 1 or 0 and get the sum of each (number of 1s and number of 0s). It appears that the last process to return 1 is the only one being waited on in the while loop.

The program is to take file names as command line arguments and determine if they exist or not. For each file name (exist or not) a new process is forked via a fan relation to the parent and if the file does not exist it returns error status. If it does exist it returns success status. However only the last PID is showing in the while loop.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t pid;
    int i, stat, suc = 0, fail = 0;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: ./wordcount.exe [File_1] [File_2] [...] [File_n]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0){

            if (access(argv[i], F_OK) != 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Child process %ld for %s does not exist\n", (long)getpid(), argv[i]);
                return 1;           
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "Child process %ld for %s: Number of words is: %d\n", (long)getpid(), argv[i], 0);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while(1){

        if (waitpid(pid, &stat, 0) == -1 && errno != EINTR) {
            printf("pid var = %d\tstat=%d\n", pid, stat);
            fail++;
            break;
        } else {
            printf("pid var = %d\tstat=%d\n", pid, stat);
            suc++;
        }
    }

    printf("Parent process created %d processes to count %d words in %d files\n", (suc + fail), 0, (suc + fail));
    printf("%d file(s) have been counted successfully!\n", suc);
    printf("%d file(s) did not exist.\n", fail);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Current output with 2 existing files and 2 non-existing:

$ ./wordcount.exe input_file_1.txt input_file_2.txt inputfail1 inputfail2
Child process 3565 for input_file_1.txt: Number of words is: 0
Child process 3566 for input_file_2.txt: Number of words is: 0
Child process 3567 for inputfail1 does not exist
Child process 3568 for inputfail2 does not exist
pid var = 3568  stat=256
pid var = 3568  stat=256
Parent process created 2 processes to count 0 words in 2 files
1 file(s) have been counted successfully!
1 file(s) did not exist.
```

Comment: Well sure, you overwrite the variable `pid` on every iteration of the `for` loop, so when it finishes you only see the last value.  If you want to keep track of all the pids, one `int` variable won't suffice; you'd need an array.  Or use `waitpid(-1, &stat, 0)` to wait for any of the running children.

Comment: Also your `if(waitpid(...) == -1)` doesn't test whether the child returned 0 or 1, it tests whether the child existed at all.   So your one "success" is because the child with the last pid did exit (whether with exit code 0 or 1, you don't check), and your one "failure" is because you are then trying to wait for the same pid again, and it no longer exists because you already waited for it.  The exit code is in the `stat` variable whose value you don't use in computing `suc` and `fail`.

Comment: Either save all the PIDs in an array so you can wait for each of them. Or use `wait()` instead of `waitpid()` so you don't need to specify the PID.

Answer (score 0):

I did a combination of both of you guys' help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "restartwait.h"

char* ReadLine();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t pid[argc - 1];
    int i, stat, suc = 0, fail = 0;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: ./wordcount.exe [File_1] [File_2] [...] [File_n]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        pid[i-1] = fork();
        if (pid[i-1] == 0){

            if (access(argv[i], F_OK) != 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Child process %ld for %s does not exist\n", (long)getpid(), argv[i]);
                return 1;           
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "Child process %ld for %s: Number of words is: %d\n", (long)getpid(), argv[i], 0);
            return 0;
        } else if (pid[i-1] == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "fork() returned an error. Exiting...\n");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            //parent
            //printf("I am the parent. PID: %d\n", getpid());
        }
    }

    int j=0;
    while (1){
        int x = wait(&stat);
        if (x == -1 && errno != EINTR){
            break;
        }
        //catch errors
        else if (x == -1){
            printf("-1\n");
            break;
        }

        if (stat == 0){
            suc++;
        } else if (stat > 0){
            fail++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    
    printf("Parent process created %d processes to count %d words in %d files\n", (suc + fail), 0, (suc + fail));
    printf("%d file(s) have been counted successfully!\n", suc);
    printf("%d file(s) did not exist.\n", fail);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your explanation of your code?

Comment: @JeremyCaney So in the solution I am waiting on all children with `wait` instead of a specific one with `waitpid`. That loop runs forever until all children have been waited on. Meanwhile the parent is checking the return status stored in `stat` and incrementing the variables accordingly. If for some reason `stat` returned `-1` an error has occurred and it breaks. Hope that clears it up.